# Grails date & date range constraint?

Tags: grails, date, constraints

I have been Googling for a bit trying to find the answer on this one.  I am going to guess the answer might be a custom constraint, but I am going to ask anyway, whether Grails supports the notion of a Date constraint, similar to how it supports email or credit card constraints?

I was thinking it would be very useful to have a date and furthermore, a standard way to specify the range.

I am asking here because I can't seem to find any information on such a constraint, although it appears to be hinted at in http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/range.html

Thank you!

Comment: That range constraint is for a range of numbers, not dates.  A custom validator is probably what you need as Grails doesn't have anything built in.  There could be a plugin, but I don't know of one.

Comment: Yes, I would also say you have to go for custom validation

Comment: @Gregg - It says [right in the documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/range.html) that you can have **an IntRange, dates or any object that implements Comparable and provides next and previous methods for navigation.**  If you always wanted to validate against a fixed range, it's supposed to work.  Of course, that's probably not very useful for dates!

Comment: Ah, missed that @OverZealous.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Looks like Don has the right answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
static constraints = {
    someDate(min: Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', '2011-10-10'), 
            max: Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', '2012-10-10'))    
}
```

Comment: One gotcha here... Those dates don't get evaluated each time validation runs - They're either evaluated at start up time or first invocation time.  So things like `someDate(min:newDate, max:new Date()+10)` start becoming problematic after the app has been running for 10 days.  You can correct the problem with a custom validator if you run into this situation.

Comment: @proflux I've changed the example to avoid this problem, thanks

Comment: @Dónal I still think this problem persists, as you evaluate Date.parse() in a static context. Therefor I think that proflux' comment is valid, and that you need a custom validator. It could be clever if Grails would allow you to give a closure as an argument to min: and max: and that way allow for it to be evaluated at runtime.